# why my flutter has no permission to open file

Tags: flutter, terminal

I am new to flutter, when I run flutter doctor in my terminal, it gives me the following erreor:

```
Flutter failed to run "/Users/ding/Library/Group
Containers/group.com.apple.notes/Media/E6E06D5A-6AAA-4277-A012-075BEEB07DD6/Andr
oid Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has
read/write permissions for the current user.
```

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions for installing on macos carefully?  In particular, you never typed sudo, correct?

Comment: I found that I don't have a folder called Group Containers....I have not idea why flutter need to run this commend